# Is there possible query to compute for the total profits per category in 2 table?

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.5

How do I do.

Here is the table 1 for payments
[Payments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9epG3.png)

| paymentid | Unit | branch | tenantid | name | amount | note | dateofpayment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bodega | Santo | 1 | Alsace Alsace | 10000 | REFRESHED DATA | 2022-12-27 16:22:53 |
| 2 | Bodega | Santo | 1 | Alsace Alsace | 1333 | wawdad | 2022-11-22 19:17:45 |
| 3 | Bodega | Jacinto MRT | 1 | Alsace Alsace | 1000 | dwadawdaw | 2023-01-01 19:36:13 |
| 4 | Bodega | Jacinto MRT | 4 | awd awdawd | 2000 | awd | 2022-12-25 15:45:49 |

Here is the table 2 for expenses
[Expenses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqcyq.png)

| expensesid | branch | typeofexpenses | amount | note | dateofexpenses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Santo | Electricity | 299 | aadadad | 2022-12-27 00:00:00 |
| 3 | Maligno | Electricity | 20 | daawd | 2022-12-27 00:00:00 |
| 4 | Santo | Electricity | 11111 | adawd | 2022-12-27 00:00:00 |
| 5 | Santo | Electricity | 30 | ef | 2022-12-27 00:00:00 |
| 7 | Santo | Electricity | 100 | we | 2023-01-17 19:56:26 |
| 8 | Santo | Electricity | 200 | dw | 2022-12-25 15:45:49 |

and I want to get the total profit of this  table per branch
here is the query I use:

```
SELECT payments.branch , SUM(payments.amount) AS Profits, SUM(expenses.amount) AS Expenses, SUM(payments.amount)  - SUM(expenses.amount) AS Total
FROM payments
RIGHT OUTER JOIN expenses
on payments.branch = expenses.branch
GROUP BY payments.branch
```

I tried the above query but there result is like this:

[image: REsult of Query]

Expected result

| Branch | Payments | Expenses | Profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Santo | 11333 | 11740 | -407 |
| Jacinto MRT | 3000 | 0 | 3000 |
| Maligno | 0 | 20 | -20 |

IF YOU WANT TO TRY IT ON YOUR MACHINE HERE IS THE QUERY

```
CREATE TABLE `expenses` (
  `expensesid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `branch` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `typeofexpenses` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `note` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dateofexpenses` datetime NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO `expenses` (`expensesid`, `branch`, `typeofexpenses`, `amount`, `note`, `dateofexpenses`) VALUES
(2, 'Santo', 'Electricity', 299, 'aadadad', '2022-12-27 00:00:00'),
(3, 'Maligno', 'Electricity', 20, 'daawd', '2022-12-27 00:00:00'),
(4, 'Santo', 'Electricity', 11111, 'adawd', '2022-12-27 00:00:00'),
(5, 'Santo', 'Electricity', 30, 'ef', '2022-12-27 00:00:00'),
(7, 'Santo', 'Electricity', 100, 'we', '2023-01-17 19:56:26'),
(8, 'Santo', 'Electricity', 200, 'dw', '2022-12-25 15:45:49');

CREATE TABLE `payments` (
  `paymentid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Unit` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `branch` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tenantid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `note` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dateofpayment` datetime NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `payments` (`paymentid`, `Unit`, `branch`, `tenantid`, `name`, `amount`, `note`, `dateofpayment`) VALUES
(1, 'Bodega', 'Santo', 1, 'Alsace Alsace', 10000, 'REFRESHED DATA', '2022-12-27 16:22:53'),
(2, 'Bodega', 'Santo', 1, 'Alsace Alsace', 1333, 'wawdad', '2022-11-22 19:17:45'),
(3, 'Bodega', 'Jacinto MRT', 1, 'Alsace Alsace', 1000, 'dwadawdaw', '2023-01-01 19:36:13'),
(4, 'Bodega', 'Jacinto MRT', 4, 'awd awdawd', 2000, 'awd', '2022-12-25 15:45:49');
```

Comment: We do not accept data as picture. See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: it isn't related to my problem.

Comment: Do you want to solve your problem? if you want then you must work for this, including the correct design of the question.

Comment: Thanks. It helps a lot sorry for misunderstanding your suggestion 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is to start with the full list of branches (subquery b) and then left join to the aggregated data of the other two tables (sub queries p & e) -

```
SELECT
    b.branch AS Branch,
    IFNULL(p.amount, 0) AS Payments,
    IFNULL(e.amount, 0) AS Expenses,
    IFNULL(p.amount, 0) - IFNULL(e.amount, 0) AS Profit
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT branch FROM expenses UNION SELECT DISTINCT branch FROM payments) AS b
LEFT JOIN (SELECT branch, SUM(amount) amount FROM payments GROUP BY branch) AS p ON b.branch = p.branch
LEFT JOIN (SELECT branch, SUM(amount) amount FROM expenses GROUP BY branch) AS e ON b.branch = e.branch;
```

As you are using MariaDB >= 10.2.1 we can use [Common Table Expressions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/non-recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/) to improve readability. And as you have stated that you have a separate table for `branches`, I will assume `branches (branchid, name)` and `branchid` instead of `branch` in `expenses` and `payments` tables.

```
WITH payments AS (
    SELECT branchid, SUM(amount) total FROM payments GROUP BY branchid
), expenses AS (
    SELECT branchid, SUM(amount) total FROM expenses GROUP BY branchid
)
SELECT
    b.name AS Branch,
    IFNULL(p.total, 0) AS Payments,
    IFNULL(e.total, 0) AS Expenses,
    IFNULL(p.total, 0) - IFNULL(e.total, 0) AS Profit
FROM branches AS b
LEFT JOIN payments AS p ON b.branchid = p.branchid
LEFT JOIN expenses AS e ON b.branchid = e.branchid;
```

Comment: thank a lot It works fine. I'll study it to improve my knowledge on constructing queries :)

Comment: Did you denormalize the structure for the sake of simplifying your question or are you tables really structured like this? For example, the branches should exist in their own table and be referenced by id (or code if you have unique branch codes).

Comment: yes it has all their own tables

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Obviously, appropriate indices are really important and will have a significant impact on performance of queries like these as your dataset grows. If you add your branches table and the indices to your question, I will update my answer.

Comment: version 10.5.13